# Стрелка у HTML-элемента

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать стрелку вправо, как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #FF6A50;
}
div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 100%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FF6A50;
 }
```

```html
<div>D</div>
```

**Вариант 2**

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #FF6A50;
}
div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; right: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FF6A50;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
div > span{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div><span>D</span></div>
```

**Вариант 3**

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #FF6A50;
}
div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 100%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #FF6A50;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 50%);
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 50%);
 }
```

```html
<div>D</div>
```

**Вариант 4**

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #FF6A50;
}
div:after{
  content: '\25BA';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; right: -30px;    
  color: #FF6A50;  
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

```html
<div>D</div>
```

**Вариант 5**

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  padding-right: 15px; /*100px-85px=15px*/
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #FF6A50;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(85% 35%, 100% 50%, 85% 65%, 85% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 85% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(85% 35%, 100% 50%, 85% 65%, 85% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 85% 0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
div:hover{
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  background: #008080;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 85%, 65% 85%, 50% 100%, 35% 85%, 0 85%, 0 0, 100% 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 85%, 65% 85%, 50% 100%, 35% 85%, 0 85%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div>D</div>
```